# Should I block ftp & mail in urls?

Tags: htaccess

Should I block ftp & mail in urls that shows up in the Latest Visitors Logs?

Are they a bot, hacker or misconfigured server?

Examples: **ftp**.somesite.com, **mail**.somesite.com

IF so; how would I block only those words in htaccess?

Comment: Are these valid sub-domains? If not, are they showing up in your example.com site log files? Even with log file data, we may never know what the pay-off would be, but I suspect this is a script-kiddie looking for vulnerabilities. Many hosts create these sub-domains by default- not sure why. I suspect there is no danger, but I would block them in .htaccess anyway- perhaps redirect them to a bad site. ;-)

Comment: I have seen many spam/hacking attempts from .ua, .ru and .cn.  It's phun watching them try & hack a non-wp site...

Comment: Yep Script-kiddie stuff. You can block if you want. Do you need code??

Comment: My site is set-up to attract this activity. It is rather fun to waste their time! Plus I am a tattle-tale by posting them on my site which I am working on and is getting better and better each day. Free content! Yeahhhh!!!

Comment: Yes, I need the Code 8)

Answer (score 1):

If these sub-domains do not exist and these requests are being handled by your site, you can safely block them using .htaccess. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^ftp\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^mail\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L] # manually added
```

Obviously replace example.com with your domain name keeping the \ [back-slash] before the . [dot] to properly escape.

Of course you can replace the RewriteRule with a redirect:

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.a-bad-place.com/ [R,L]
```

-- or --

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.house-of-mouse.com/ [R,L]
```

Replace www.a-bad-place.com or www.house-of-mouse.com with a site of your choice. (Just for humor of course- I am not advising redirecting an attack on another site. But if you do, I won't tell. [That's a joke son. Laugh. - Foghorn Leghorn] )

Comment: NOTE: these are "Some Other Sites" trying to access my site.  The funny thing is mail.mysite.com links to sosoulmate.com - don't you just love that?  I could care less because me@mydomain.com still works.

Comment: @EastTexas Ooopppssss! I may have had a brain-fart. Mail.example.com is the attacking site? That is how I wrote the .htaccess.

Comment: @EastTexas Perhaps this is new to you, but as you get older and become an old fart (like I am) and more and more gassy, these various bubbles to not always exhaust properly and rise up to the brain causing havoc. This is why it is important to keep your ears clean and blow your nose. But do not have a lit cigarette while doing this. It will singe your ear/nose hairs at the very least which is good, but can otherwise really ruin your day. (another joke)

Comment: Possibly a bit of an aside, but... `REMOTE_HOST` is only set (to the host) if `HostnameLookups` is enabled on the server, otherwise it's likely to contain the IP address (or not be set at all). Although I guess it is enabled if you are getting hosts (rather than IP addresses) in your access logs? However, `HostnameLookups` is Off by default - for performance reasons - since Apache will otherwise need to make DNS lookups for every request.

Comment: @w3d Excellent point!! Some installs/builds enable this, but Apache by default does not. I forgot about that. Thanks!!

Comment: It's shared web host.  Most of the time I get IP, and sometimes even IP mixed with the domain name.

Comment: @EastTexas In the apache2.conf file there should be a setting *HostnameLookups On*. You may want to check for this. I suspect you have it enabled- but check anyway. This is what w3d was talking about. It is often commented out.

Comment: I think it will default to the IP when it doesn't resolve. Some domains will contain "what looks like" the IP address (without the dots), as part of a subdomain. It's possible your web host does some post processing of the access logs, rather than looking up in real-time?! But this would mean `REMOTE_HOST` would not be set in .htaccess. To be honest I would be/am surprised that your _shared_ host would enable `HostnameLookups`, to [quote from the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html), "this configuration is not recommended since it can significantly slow the server".

Comment: Whats the code for HostnameLookups?

Comment: @w3d That *Apache* statement was written way back in version 1.god-knows and remains. Speed is not an issue these days. In fact, I have had this option on for about 15 years without an issue. The other sub-domain.domain.tld(s) that you mentioned are just IP pools- some are hosts and some are subscribers. Of course you know that, but I am mentioning this for GP.

Comment: @EastTexas In your apache2.conf file you will find *HostnameLookups* which is sometimes commented out. You can do a search for it when you edit the file. It will either be set to *on* or *off*. You will want to un-comment it and if it is set to off change it to *HostnameLookups On*.

Comment: BINGO w3d! -  Some domains will contain "what looks like" the IP address (without the dots), as part of a subdomain.

Comment: Although if you are on a "shared web host", as you say, then you are not going to be able to access the server config in order to enable (or disable) this option.

Comment: @EastTexas Back when I was a web host, we turned this on by default for all our servers. I suspect this is still true.